# create Database with .net installshield 2015

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, installshield

I'm trying to create an installer file that installs a database using install shield 2015.

I'm following this link
[Walkthrough: Using a Custom Action to Create a Database at Installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49b92ztk(v=vs.80).aspx)

Since this link refers to an older install shield I didn't managed to make it work. I have created an install file in my main windows form application, which you can see in the below code.

```
public partial class DeployInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection masterConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
    public DeployInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private string GetSql(string Name)
    {

        try
        {
            // Gets the current assembly.
            Assembly Asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            // Resources are named using a fully qualified name.
            Stream strm = Asm.GetManifestResourceStream(Asm.GetName().Name + "." + Name);

            // Reads the contents of the embedded file.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(strm);
            return reader.ReadToEnd();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Interaction.MsgBox("In GetSQL: " + ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteSql(string Sql)
    {
        masterConnection.ConnectionString = "data source=.//SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=master;integrated security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Application Name=EntityFramework";

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand Command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(Sql, masterConnection);

        // Initialize the connection, open it, and set it to the "master" database
        Command.Connection.Open();
        try
        {
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Closing the connection should be done in a Finally block
            Command.Connection.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void AddDBTable()
    {
        try
        {
            // Creates the database.
            //ExecuteSql("master", "CREATE DATABASE " + strDBName);

            // Creates the tables.
            ExecuteSql( GetSql("sql.txt"));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Reports any errors and abort.
            //Interaction.MsgBox("In exception handler: " + ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
    }


    public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        base.Install(stateSaver);
        AddDBTable();
    }
}
```

Supposedly this piece of code provides the user with the ability of doing both the installation of the system and the corresponding database. For some reason only the system is being installed. When attempting to install the database, something is preventing from successfully completing. Unfortunately, I cannot pinpoint the reason why because it doesn't give out an error with the reason. It could be that its never being started or that I did something wrong.

Any guide would be appreciated.

Comment: Your connection string is incorrect. It should be `.\SQLEXPRESS`. Try and see if that helps.

Comment: no it didn't work, tried also manually write the sql statement but also with no luck. I maybe didn't put the install file in the correct place. because I think the install file isn't launching the code listed above